# Linux bypass SSL certificate validation not working correctly RabbitMQ, Any solutions available?

Tags: c#, linux, ssl, .net-core, rabbitmq

I am currently trying to connect to RabbitMQ via .NET and when i try to bypass the SSL certificate validation i get the following error:

```
 Unhandled Exception: RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException:
 None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> System.AggregateException:
 One or more errors occurred. (Authentication failed, see inner exception.) ---> 
 System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, 
 see inner exception. ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL 
 error - SSL_ERROR_SSL. ---> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException:
 error:14090087:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:cert length mismatch
```

On the server SSL2 and SSL3 has been disabled. We are trying to us TLS1.2 which is enabled on the server.

This is the code that i am running on Linux and i have tested this code on a Windows machine and it has worked. It seems that the issue only arises on a Linux machine. This is an Amazon Linux Distro, but this issue comes up on Ubuntu as well.

```
 public void Connection(bool useTLS){

     ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
     factory.Port = 5671;
     factory.UserName = "user";
     factory.Password = "password";
     factory.VirtualHost = "";
     factory.HostName = "develop.example.com";


     factory.Ssl.Enabled = true;
     factory.Ssl.Version = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
     factory.Ssl.CertificateValidationCallback = 
       (sender, ConsumerTagConvention, chain, SslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
     factory.Ssl.AcceptablePolicyErrors |= 
        System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors | 
        System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch | 
        System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable;

     IConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();

     if (conn.IsOpen)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Connected");
         conn.Close();
     }
     else
         Console.WriteLine("Failed");
     }
```

This is a snippet of the code used to connect, as you can see we add SSL policy errors and as well as `CertificateValidationCallBack` method. 
Not sure if this just a Linux issue and if there is some kind of work around

Comment: Please see [my response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/jqf-eFGIzTE/qPBvJaWfBwAJ). In short, there is not enough information to help you.

Comment: @LukeBakken I found the issue, it was actually with the cert i was using.

Comment: Please follow up here and on `rabbitmq-users` with what you found concerning your certificate. There is a good chance it will help someone else in the future.